# как получить названия домена внутри файла store nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

мне нужно получить названия домена и протокола чтобы использовать внутри actions в store. вот мой код:

```
    let domain = window.location.protocol + window.location.hostname;

export const actions = {

    async addUser({ commit }, data) {
        try {
            const res = await this.$axios.$post(`${domain}/api/user/create`, data);
            if (res.status === 'success') {
                commit('setUser', res.data.user);
            }
            return res;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }

}
```

но почемуто такую ошибку выдаёт: window is not defined. может я что-то делаю не так. я еще не оченто хорошо разбираюс в nuxtjs.

Answer (score 0):

`window` будет доступен в `store` не всегда, например, если обращаешься к `store` в `asyncData`, то ошибка будет именно той, которую ты получаешь.

Лучше получи домен, например, в `mounted` и передай его в `action` в `payload` (в твоём случае `data`), посредством `dispatch`:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    const domain = window.location.protocol + window.location.hostname
    this.$store.dispatch('addUser', domain)
  })
}
```

Comment: все понял, спасибо вам